# Incremental batch processing in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In our spark application, we are running multiple batch processes everyday. sources for these batch process are different like Oracle, mongoDB, Files. We are storing different value for incremental processing based on source like latest timestamp for some oracle tables, ID for some oracle table, list for some file system and using those values for next incremental run.

Currently  calculation of these offset value are dependent on source types, we need to customize code to store this value every time when we add new source type.
Is there any generic way to resolve this issue like checkpoint in streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to look into the destination for the last written partition, or get some max(primary_key) and then based on that value select data from the source database to write during the current run.

There would be no need to store anything, you would just need to supply to your batch processing algorithm the table name, source type, and primary key/timestamp column. The algorithm would then find the latest value you already have.

It really depends on your load philosophy and how your storage is divided; if you have raw/source/prepared layers. It is a good idea to load data in a raw format which can be easily compared to the original source in order to do what I described above.

Alternatives include:

- Writing a file which contains that primary column and the latest value, your batch job would read this file to determine what to read next.
- Updating the job execution configuration with an argument corresponding to the latest value, so on the next run the latest value is passed to your algorithm.